# The gradient of expectation of an objective function

Tags: machine-learning

Denoting $x$ : 2D image,
$\delta $~$ N(0,I)$,
$\theta=x+\sigma\delta$,
$F(x)$ : objective function, 
$\pi(\theta|x)$ : search distribution,
we have $\nabla_x E_{\pi(\theta|x)}[F(\theta)]= E_{\pi(\theta|x)}[F(\theta)\nabla_xlog(\pi(\theta|x))]$.

But suddenly they say that $\nabla_x E_{\pi(\theta|x)}[F(\theta)] \approx \frac{1}{\sigma n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta _i F(\theta+\sigma\delta_i)$.

How is the approximation formed?

We can approximate the expectation using $n$ samples, but why $\delta_iF(\theta+\sigma\delta_i)$?

I'm reading a machine learning paper and want to know the missing links as stated above in section 2.1.1.

The paper is : A. Ilyas, L. Engstrom, A. Athalye, and J. Lin, “Black-box Adversarial Attacks with Limited Queries and Information,” Available: http://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08598.

Thank you in advance.